# Crystal Reports ... I'm sure it's a parenthesis issue but

Tags: crystal-reports

I am wanting results that match my date parameters, DO NOT include the Ordinance Number "ECite" and that match my address parameter in either of two fields, the "Address" or "Vicinity" fields.    I have moved parenthesis all over the place and have researched for the last three days but get all sort of results based on the parenthesis but none that provide the described results.   Please point me in the right direction and/or tell me what to Google...Thank you,

MY CURRENT FORMULA:

```
{Citation.Offense_Date} in {?StartDate} to {?EndDate} and
not ({CITATION_CHARGE.Ordinance_Number} like "ECite") and
({Citation.Address} like "*" & {?Address} & "*" OR
{Citation.Vicinity} like "*" & {?Address} & "*")
```

This current formula does everything BUT returns the results that match my "Vicinity" parameter

Thank you,

Comment: show us some sample data and your expected results plz

Comment: My data consists of the following fields:  Offense_Date; Citation_Number; Ordinance_Number; Charge; and two location fields which can be used either / or:  Address and Vicinity.      I want just a line item list of all citations in the date range but with the ability to search both the address and vicinity fields for the street name.   I also want to eliminate all citations charges that have the ordinance number of "ECite" (which is just an operating fee and not officially a charge, therefore doesn't need to be shown).